# Xcode debugger in submodule

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

Working on an iOS App I'm using an static library integrated as a submodule. No problem, but when I want to step into a method of this submodule while debugging the debugger just step over that method call.

I guess it's related to the Build settings but I don't have any idea.

Thanks for your help!

kober

Comment: Sounds like the static library isn't being built in debug mode (i.e. no symbols are available).

Comment: If you have the source for that static library, you could temporarily remove the static library, build with the code in your project, and then you can step into the code. If you don't have the source code for that static library, then there's nothing meaningful for you to step into!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot step into the library code unless you have source code for it.
This is the purpose of libs, if you make your own you may want to prevent others to look how its built. If you want to check library function correctness you have two ways:

1. Get the source code - which is in most cases impossible unless you get it from the author
2. Do unit testing. Check if library function's arguments give correct results.

If you do have the source code for the lib you have to set its build to debug mode, so you can provide symbols for Xcode to get through library's methods.